# Split a string in java according to characters with even or odd order

Tags: java, string, split

You input a word which is a string. What I want to do is to put the letters in an odd position in a variable and those on an even position in another variable...
But I have been reading online and all I can find is how to split by a specific character like: "/", "-" or "`". But I don`t have one.. show what should I use...

Should I solve this in an other way....

EX:

```
String S = "alfabet";
```

and I want to print out:

```
odd = "afbl"; 
even = "lae";
System.out.println(odd + "  " + even);
```

Comment: `S.toCharArray()` then iterate this array has you wish to concat the character. Understand that you will not find a ready-to-use method to do that, it would never be used. You need to implement the logic yourself.

Comment: Javadoc is your friend: [String.charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) is an other useful method.

Comment: @AxelH What's the benefit in copying the string to a char-array? You can get each character from the `String` using `charAt`

Comment: @khelwood It was simpler to explain that it was possible to get the array to iterate instead that a method was able to get a character at a position in the array used by `String` class. So mostly because I tried to be concise and was a bit lazy... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used two strings called odd and even and set both of them to be empty then i iterate throught all the letters of the string s and add the even characters to even and odd characters to odd like the following:

```
String S = "alfabet";
            String odd="";String even="";
            for(int c=0;c<S.length();c++)
            {
                if(c%2==0)odd+=S.charAt(c);
                else even+=S.charAt(c);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

```
int i = 0;
StringBuilder oddString = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder evenString = new StringBuilder();
while(i++ < S.length())
{
    if(i & 1){
        oddString.append(S.charAt(i));
    }else{
        evenString.append(S.charAt(i));
    }
}
System.out.println("Even String: " + evenString);
System.out.println("Odd String: " + oddString);
```